# Optimising a script to scan files in a folder

Tags: php, algorithm, directory

I have my folder **/images** (with ~ *95.000 files*), and i check every file if is in the database.

**Table :** images

**Row :** hash

The folder containt all my image with sha1 name.

I use `shuffle($images);` to make sure the verification is random, otherwise it only verifies the first 35,000 images.

If I go over 35,000 checks, the script puts a timeout and the page blocks it.

Example name of an image : **d0a0bb3149bea2335e8784812fef706ad0a13156.jpg**

**My Script :**

1. I select the images in the database
2. I'm putting it in a array
3. I make the array random (to avoid always checking the first 35,000
   images)
4. I create a array of images file in the folder **/images**
5. I check for missing database files using the array created by the
   `opendir();` function
6. I display the answer

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$images = [];
$q = $mysqli->query('SELECT hash FROM images');
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc())
{
    $images[] = $r['hash'].'.jpg';
}

shuffle($images);

$i_hors_bdd = 0;
$images_existent_hors_bdd = [];

if($dh = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images'))
{
    while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {
        if(!in_array($file, $fichiers_a_exclures))
        {
            if(!is_sha1($file) OR !in_array($file, $images))
                $images_existent_hors_bdd[] = '<p><a href="?del='.$file.'">Name of File: '.$file.'</a></p>';
        }

        if($i_hors_bdd > 35000)
        {
            break;
        }

        $i_hors_bdd++;
    }
}

closedir($dh);


if(count($images_existent_hors_bdd) > 0)
{
    echo '<p>Image exist, but not in the databse.</p>';

    sort($images_existent_hors_bdd);

    foreach($images_existent_hors_bdd as $image_existe_hors_bdd)
        echo $image_existe_hors_bdd;
}

else
    echo '<p>All images are in datase.</p>';

echo '<p>'.$i_hors_bdd.' images checked.</p>';
```

So my question is: How can I optimize this script to improve the speed of the script to allow checking more images without blocking the script? Knowing that my VPS is not very powerful and I don't have SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to consider or try:

- Concatenate '.jpg' to `hash` in the sql, then use [`fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all) into a numeric array.
- use [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to build an array of files in the directory
- use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to remove `$fichiers_a_exclures` and `$images`
- iterate over this smallest array to do the `sha1` test

Comment: I did as you told me, in fact the page is generated in seconds.

But when I look at my 2 arrays, I know I have about 20 missing images, but in the array_diff function it gives me nothing.

I don't get it.

And I used the class new DirectoryIterator($dir); rather than scandir() which is faster according to the tests.

Comment: I can only think of dozens of potentials, perhaps edit  the new code into the question (keep the orig code so the answer stays relevant). Or a pastebin or a gist. If array_diff is giving "nothing" then either 1) there are no missing images or 2) the array arguments are in the wrong order or 3) the arrays don't contain what you think they do or 4) something else.

Comment: I swapped the arrays in the array_diff, put the biggest one first and got the missing images. I didn't know that this function worked like that.

Thanks for your advice =)